# Call an action from another action without return statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionmethod

This is part of my Controller class:

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 1)
{
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {  
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        dr = dt.Rows[0];

        TempData["AgentId"] = dr[0].ToString();
        TempData["AgentCode"] = dr[1].ToString();
        TempData["CenterName"] = dr[2].ToString();
        TempData["LevelName"] = dr[3].ToString();

        Session["AgentId"] = dr[0].ToString();
        Session["LogInSession"] = SessionId;

        return RedirectToAction("DashBoard", this.View(new AgentDetails { AgentId = Session["AgentId"].ToString() }));
        //return this.View("DashBoard", new AgentDetails { AgentId = Session["AgentId"].ToString()});
    }
```

I want to pass this argument and and call this action method separately. Is this possible?

Comment: So what problem are you having? And why would you want to use `return View()` instead of `return RedirectToAction()`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i am sending the values to lay out view so in this process it does not render `@Model.AgentId`. So I am trying to use `return View()` and want to call that action method so that my data can be passed to that view.

Comment: Of course it does (if you have initialized a model and set its properties based on the value of the `AgentId` parameter you passing to it. But why in the world are you passing a complex object to a GET method like (if any properties of `AgentDetails` are complex objects or collections it would fails. It should be `return RedirectToAction("DashBoard", new { AgentId = Session["AgentId"] });` which redirects to `public ActionResult DashBoard(int agentId)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yep I got it. Gonna try this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An action is just a function. You can call it like any other function.

```
var result = Dashboard();
if(result.xxxx) // do whatever
return View(new AgentDetails { AgentId = Session["AgentId"].ToString() });
```

If that is what you want to do, then why don't you just refactor `Dashboard` code out into a method you can reuse?

Comment: yes actually i want to same thing you suggested. I am sending this parameter to layout view in that case action result in not executing it just renders the view.